# initializing a new list each loop in sequence to hold different values

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, iteration

I want to ask a conceptual question with maybe an example for clarification. I am pulling details about video games from an API. At the moment I am having the details separated per game inside of a results array and this array is printed to the console each time the loop is run. Now I am trying to find a way to put each game into it's own list. That way I can call a specific list for a specific game per call of the API.

I my head I envision something like:

```
result = [gameData]

for each game loop:
  list[i] = result
```

Resulting in something like:

```
list1
list2
list3
```

Each list containing a separate game's details.
Now I have seen a lot of talk about lists within lists when looking up this issue on StackOverflow but I am wondering if that I am imagining would be possible in python.

Let me know if you can think of anything or if you need more clarification.

Comment: better create list or dictionary for all lists - as list `all_data = list()` and  `all_data.append( [gameData] )` or as dict `all_data = dict()` and `all_data[game_name] = [gameData]`

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
We need a *clear* statement of what you want to do, not a vague overview.

Answer (score 1):

Furas' post about placing these lists into a dictionary was the appropriate solve for my problem. For some reason I cannot credit them on this so I will credit you here.

The solution was simple:

```
all_games = dict()
i = 0
for games in message_json:
  all_games[i] = result
  i += 1
print(all_games)
```